# Default job priority on AS400 machine

Tags: ibm-midrange, job-scheduling, ibm-installation-manager

What is default job priority, if i am submitting job without giving any priority to JOB.

I am trying to submit a JOB through below command

SBMJOB CMD(JAVA CLASS(test.jar) PARM(true) OUTPUT(*NONE)) JOB(MYTESTJOBNAME)

What will be the run priority for this job.
Any help appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

**Short Answer**

For Batch jobs the default `Run Priority` is 50, and for interactive jobs it is 20. This can only be changed by using `CHGJOB` for a running job. Two other priorities `Job priority` and `Output priority` can be set on the job description or with `SBMJOB`.

**Longer Answer**

The `Run Priority` for a job is specified in its Class which is determined by the routing entry in the subsystem description. You can see Subsystem descriptions by using `DSPSBSD`, and Classes using `WRKCLS`. Let's run through the default batch system and find where the run priority is picked up.

On the command line, type:

```
DSPSBSD QBATCH
```

On the resulting screen key option `7` and press `Enter`.

You will have one or more routing entries on this screen. The last one is the default. That is any job that comes through the job queue that doesn't match any of the specific routing entries will pick up the last one with compare value `*ANY`. You should see that the program to be run is `QCMD`. That is the command processor. And the Class should be `QBATCH`. Note the library name, we will need it later. If the above is not the case you have a highly customized system and the short answer does not apply, or your controlling subsystem is not `QCTL`.

Let's look at class QBATCH, type:

```
WRKCLS <lib>/QBATCH
```

`<lib>` is the library for the class noted earlier. You will see several performance related items on this screen, including the run priority. This is where `Run Priority` comes from, and this is where you can permanently change the run priority for various classes of jobs. If you run this down for subsystems `QINTER`, and `QCTL` you will find different *default* run priorities for different classes of jobs.

**Other Priorities**

*Job Priority* - is the order in which a job will be taken off the job queue for processing. It can also be used to limit the number of jobs running in a subsystem. For example, you can set a limit on the number of active jobs in a subsystem that had Job Priority 1 on the Job Queue. Lower number runs first. This is all actually very complex, and the next job to run will depend on the job queue and it's sequence number in the subsystem description, the max active for the job queue, the job priority, the Max by priority, and the number of active jobs in the subsystem by job queue and priority. Best to read the [Work management manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaks/rzaks.pdf?view=kc) if you want to know more about this.

*Output Priority* - specifies the order that spooled jobs print from an output queue. Lower number prints first.

Answer (score 0):

The default priority for a submitted job is 50.

This is specified on the job description, but can be overridden by on the `SBMJOB` command.

Comment: Three types of priorities are associated with job. 1 Job priority 2 Output priority and 3 is Run priority. Can u explain me difference in between then and what u recommend me to set priority for above command.

Comment: Run priority is the most important ... it controls how often the job gets CPU resources.  Unless you have a compelling reason, I would suggest leaving the priority at the default.